NMDS with Morisita-Horn Index: which data-transformation makes sense?
I have a community matrix of spiders, which I captured during winter in different forest stand-types.
I now want to perform an NMDs. For that I want to use the Morisita-Horn Index from R in the package vegdist:


with xij = number of individuals from species i in sample j
xik = number of individulas from species i in sample k
As far as I understood the index is well suited in order to evaluate the extent to which the stand types share species, while also integrating the similarity of the relative abundances of  the species.
I have a matrix which contains many zeros, because I captured many rare species. Here an example for how the matrix looks like:

When I apply metaMDs in R, R applies automatically a wisconsin double standardization. To be honest I do not really understand the meaning of this transformation.
At the moment I am wondering if I should even apply any transformation or if this is not necessary. In another paper of scientists which also captured spiders in winter they used hellinger transformation (calculating the relative abundance of a species in each sample and square root transform all the values). This enhances the influence of the less abundant species. For example:
Two samples from my community matrix:
1.4: 1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,11,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4.2: 0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,14,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,2,0,0,2,0,0
(abundances of 11 and 14 belong to a shared species and 1 and 6)
When I use the "horn" index without any transformation i receive a value of 0.1310861, which means that they are quite similar to each other concerning the species and their relative abundances in the samples (0 would be completely similar) and it's also obvious when looking at the data (because of the species with 11 and 14 individuals).
but when I apply the hellinger transformation before, I get a value of 0.33205, so they are less similar, as they do not share the species with the low abundances.
Of course the absolute values are not important when it comes to plotting the NMDS but I guess it would change the relationsships when considering all samples.
Does it makes sense to apply this transformation? On the one hand I would say yes, as there are more information included about the species which have lower abundances, but on the other hand, species with such low abundances might just not have been captured in another stand, even though they are also there...so it is too much including those random sampling effects....
So finally my question is:
Does it makes sense to apply a Hellinger standardization to my data instead of the wisconsin double standardization when I use the Morisita-Horn index?
Or differently asked: Which are the criteria for choosing a certain standardization?
In another paper they just square root transformed their abundance data before applying the morisita horn index. I am a bit overwhelmed.
Thank you for any suggestions!
